# How can I extend the search builder

Tags: 4.7

I'm looking to extend the search builder to accept a custom value which then can be used to filter the search results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to search using Advance search ? - If not Please give a read https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/

Comment: i don't really understand what you need. pls give an exact example and or demo it to us on the demo site.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom fields under Administer - Custom Data and Screens - Custom fields.

Make sure you check the box for "is this field searchable".

Then the field should be available for searching in Advanced Search or Search Builder.